# Cordova redirecting to a downloaded file within Library

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I am using [cordova-app-updater](https://github.com/mnill/cordova-app-updater/blob/master/www/updater.html) and cordova-plugin-file to download an amended html file from a remote server and then redirect the app to it.

The plugin allows the file to be downloaded to file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7465E774.../Library/files/cache[custom]/www[custom]/ and redirects the app to the downloaded file.

I can download the file but when I try to redirect to it window.location.href = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7465E774.../Library/files/cache/www/index.html I receive the message [Not allowed to load local resource].

It sounds like a permissions problem with IOS (I havent tried Android yet) but I have searched for days and and got no closer.

My config.xml has:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" >
<preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
<preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
```

Comment: file:// does not work anymore on iOS

Comment: any progress on this?  I am looking for similar, but need to get file to the users general `download` folder.  I can download with cordova-plugin-file & cordova-plugin-file-transfer but that stores it in a place the user can't get to.  I need a way of prompting user to select their download folder or just auto-downloading it to there.